# How to update an existing excel sheet using Linux

Tags: linux, excel

```
day     date    Pick List (Vault)   Pick List (Robot)   Time Job Completed  Checked in      Scratch Count in Library    Manually Ejected    Recalled    Scratch Onsite (EOD)    Free Slots in Library
Tuesday 1/1/2013                                        
Wednesday   1/2/2013        4       1       92              
Thursday    1/3/2013    7   11  14:39   5       73
```

Above is my excel sheet and my question is how to update each fields in the sheet everyday with the output values from various scripts.

Comment: What technology are you using? Java, C# etc???

Comment: Is your daily update as simple as appending one extra row?

Comment: I want to update excel in Linux server and send it everyday. tech - Linux bash.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save your Excel spreadsheet in `csv` format so you only need to deal with plain text.
2. Use any of your favorite techniques to append new line everyday, or use Python [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) package to read, modify and write the csv file.